# Input form - step

Tags: javascript, html, input, onsubmit

My JS code doesn't work properly when I add "step" in my input form. I need float numbers so it's `.01`. Here is my code.

```html
<div class="input">
  <label for="height">Height</label>
  <input type="number" name="height" placeholder="0.00 cm" id="height" step=".01">
</div>
```

```js
function calculateBMI() {
  const inputHeight = (document.getElementById("height").value);
  const inputWeight = (document.getElementById("weight").value);
  const bmi = inputWeight / Math.pow(inputHeight, 2).toFixed(2);

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Your BMI is ' + bmi;
  document.getElementById("result").style.display = "block";

  if (inputHeight === "" && inputWeight === "") {
    alert("Invalid input");
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "doesn't work properly"? Is it not giving you a float? Is there some other error? Does it work without adding the `step` property?

Comment: When I remove step from input form it's work properly, when I add it again, JS code doesn't work

Comment: `.value` is going to return a string, not a Number.  So there may be an issue with you trying to perform math operations upon strings

Comment: Could you still elaborate on what you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: @Taplar just I said, it's everything perfect without 'step', .value is correct but problems begin when I add step=".01" or "0.01".

Comment: Here is a fiddle where if you remove step you still get the same results: https://jsfiddle.net/0d8gf7t4/

Comment: @Taplar it cannot return string as the type of the input is number.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. I tested your code, and everything seems to work fine. We need to see more of your code.

Comment: `Math.pow(inputHeight, 2)` will work perfectly fine when `inputHeight` is a string since it casts the string to a number, so that is not the issue.

Comment: @MDMNauman to confirm my statement before I made it, I made a codepen and put the element in there, selected it, grabbed the `.value` off of it, and `console.log(typeof theValue)` and it said `string`.  So that conflicts with your assertion.

Comment: @MDMNauman you are confusing the type vs the characters themselves. Input `number` returns a string of numbers but it is still a string. If you want to see yourself, go to my above fiddle and add this code `console.log(typeof document.getElementById("height").value);` and check the console. You will see its still a string.

Comment: Furthermore, you can just stick this in your browser console. `var x = document.createElement('input');x.type="number";x.value=3;console.log(typeof x.value);
`

Comment: @Taplar upvoted your comment. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @imvain2 Yes, got that thanks for the info too.

Comment: Hello, can you say us what's showing in the console when you added the step attribute

Comment: Hello @Couldn'tBee try adding 0.01 instead of .01 and check whether it works?

Comment: @imvain2 it's work now and display result in result div but then result disappear in one second :/

Comment: @MDMNauman I tried 0.01 also but doesnt work